# Concatenate fields from related N:N custom entity

Tags: concatenation, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

For Dynamics 365 v8.2

We built a custom entity called "Product Buyers" that has a N:N relationship with Accounts via the Account ID field. The custom entity also has a field that is a lookup to Products (it holds the product name). We created this because we need three unique relationships to each Product - one for the Account and two tied to other Contacts aside from the main contact at that Account.

So on each Account record, we have a table that shows the "Product Buyer" info, which includes a column called "Products" that has that lookup field from the Product Buyers entity.

Here's the question: How do we create a single field on the Account record that is essentially a concatenation of the Product fields from all related "Product Buyer: records?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this OOB.

Create a multiline textbox field & do a custom concatenation whenever new record added or removed or updated in N:N entity. Plugins needed for real-time.

Or you can have a SSIS+Kingswaysoft package to run periodically (we call this Rollup engine) to update that Rollup textbox field.